# How do i modify the value of char *?

Tags: c, pointers, char, string-literals

Hi i have below program.

```
char *x="abc";
*x=48;
printf("%c",*x);
```

This gives me output `a`, but I expected output as `0`.

**EDIT**
Can you suggest what I can do in order to store data during runtime in

```
char *x;
```

Comment: You assign a new address to it. Did you mean to modify what it's *pointing at*?

Comment: Please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you mean the character `'0'` then *say* so.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes. I want to modify what its pointing at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't: the behaviour on attempting to is *undefined*. The string `"abc"` is a *read-only* literal (formally its type is `const char[4]`).

If you write

```
char x[] = "abc";
```

Then you *are* allowed to modify the string.

Comment: `char x[] = "abc";` is the correct syntax. ;)

Comment: It's C and @mch is right!

Comment: @mch: If I had a dollar for each time I've written that incorrectly ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba I have edited my question. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (*even try to*) to modify a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal). It causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to make use of a write-allowed memory. There are two ways.

- Allocate memory to pointer `x` (i.e, store the returned pointer via memory allocator methods to `x`), then this will be writable, and copy the string literal using `strcpy()`.

  ```
    char * x = NULL;
    if (x = malloc(DEF_SIZ)) {strcpy(x, "abc");}
  ```

  - Or, not strictly standard conforming, but shorter, `strdup()`.

    ```
    char *x = strdup("abc");
    ```
- use an array `x` and initialize it with the string literal.

  ```
  char x[] = "abc";
  ```

In all above cases, `x` (or rather, the memory location pointed by `x`) is modifiable.

Comment: There's no harm in your copying the example from my answer to make this even clearer.

Comment: @Bathsheba It's there anyway in your answer, so I did not repeat, but if you think it'll make this better, there's no harm anyway.

Comment: @mch I blame copy-paste. :)